# Почему не читаются сообщения из очереди IBM WebSphere MQ?

Tags: java, ibm

Имеем Java, Apache Camel, WebSphere App Server, WebSphere MQ.
Приложение читает очередь через Camel, в Camel попадает как компонент Connection Factory, который создается на WebSphere App Server. 
Суть вопроса такова, на моих стендах все работает держит кучу сообщений и прочее, на стенде у товарища Camel вообще не читает из очереди ничего, при этом его  WebSphere App Server настроен так же и Connection Factory тоже. При этом один раз после перезагрузки WebSphere App Server он вычитал все сообщения и потом опять не читает. Все это дико странно т.к. ошибок от Camel'a нет ни одной, в логах WebSphere App Server тоже чисто.

Посмотрели через MQExplorer на очереди висит Web Sphere MQ Client for Java процесс который читает её. Т.е. сейчас у товарища, все как у меня, только не читает нефига, в чем может быть проблема?

Можете хотя бы примерно сказать куда можно смотреть, копать, тестировать?

Answer (score 0):

1. На первый взгляд, либо очередь на MQ  указана не та у вас, либо  сообщения кто-то вычитывает другой, но сложно сказать.
2. Вы можете положить сообщение в очередь MQ через MQExplorer или RHFUtil.